# Change the text of the button from next to install after accepting license agreement?

Tags: nsis

I want to change the button text from next to install once the user accepts the license agreement. Clicking the radio button of accepting the license agreement should change the text of the button from next to install.

Comment: Adding to this, Also need the same to display the text as Upgrade in case of upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hooks that will allow you to change the text based on a event on the license page but you could change the text when you first enter the page:

```
Page license "" licshow
LicenseForceSelection radiobuttons


Function licshow
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^InstallBtn)"
FunctionEnd
```

or you can use `LicenseText "" "$(^InstallBtn)"`

If for whatever reason you feel you **have** to do this you can try the [button event plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ButtonEvent_plug-in)...

Comment: Adding to this, Need the same thing in case of upgrade. The button text should be Upgrade. How can I get this?

Comment: LicenseText can contain a variable, set it in .onInit to whatever you want the text to be...